# How does std::execution::parallel_policy interact with std::find or algorithms that modify the container?

Tags: c++, algorithm, concurrency, c++17, std

I've been recently reminded about std::algorithm, and learned about the new execution policies for std::algorithm, and would like to leverage them in my code.

I have many loops over vectors where I'm looking for a particular element (which i know to be unique) or elements that match a condition, usually in the form of `if (ele != nullptr && ele->GetID() == searchID) { /*do the thing/* }`

Now I know that looks like a prime target for using `std::find_if` as it finds the first element that matches that ID, or if I was looking for multiple `std::for_each`, but I'm worried what `std::execution::parallel_policy` or `std::execution::parallel_unsequenced_policy` may do when use them and potentially modify the container.

If somehow U have multiple elements that match a condition, `std::find_if` is supposed to find the first, but is that guaranteed if executed in parallel? Would i always get the first, and not potentially one of the others?

If using `std::for_each`, how would this handle modifications to the container? I understand I'd need to prevent data races, but wouldn't calling something like `vector::erase` cause issues with the other threads no matter what, as the container in memory would invalidate iterators?

I am aware ranges are a thing, but I'm on c++17 at present so unable to use them, but there are plans in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you do find in parallel each thread can search a chunk of the range. You then don't return the first element found by any thread but you return the element found by the first thread. Unless that didn't find anything then you return the element from the second thread. Unless that didn't find anything and so on.

As for modifying the container: You can only use parallel execution if the modification in one thread won't affect any other thread. For example `a[i] = a[i] * 2;` is fine. `a[i] = a[i - 1] + a[i - 2];` on the other hand will not work. It's your job to choose an execution policy that does not have data races.

And yes, I would expect `vector::erase` to blow up spectaculary. You would have to redesign it so each thread only swaps elements around and returns the range of remaining elements and then do a second pass to erase all the holes. But I have no idea how you would do that with `std::for_each`.